# Fitnesse : how to check if path exist

Tags: markdown, markup, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

In a newly created wiki in Fitnesse. Say we defined a path:

```
!path /home/user/mypath
```

Is there a way to verify that the path exist? or list the contents of the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. 
It is just like the Java classpath, which it configures, it defines a location where fitnesse looks for Java classes. It does not have to be a directory, it can also be a .jar, .zip or an expression with a wildcard.